# Error while importing JSON data from mongo shell to my Atlus cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I need to import data from a JSON file to a cluster in Atlas mongodb.

I looked into the documentation and found the following command

mongoimport --host centarosa-shard-0/centarosa-shard-00-00-eplsl.mongodb.net:27017,centarosa-shard-00-01-eplsl.mongodb.net:27017,centarosa-shard-00-02-eplsl.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username parvarish --password  --authenticationDatabase admin --db  --collection  --type  --file

The error that I am getting is :

Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

I also tried updating my mongodb version to 4.0.1
But still getting the same error

Please guide me through this.

Thanks

Comment: First thing I'd check would be the network whitelist (in the atlas security section) to make sure you're connecting from a computer with an IP that's allowed to connect.

Comment: Hi Willis, I have added 0.0.0.0/0 in my IP Whitelist..So that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is missing [required arguments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#examples). Try the code below, replacing the bolded values with those appropriate for your environment.

mongoimport --host centarosa-shard-0/centarosa-shard-00-00-eplsl.mongodb.net:27017,centarosa-shard-00-01-eplsl.mongodb.net:27017,centarosa-shard-00-02-eplsl.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username parvarish --password **MYPWD** --authenticationDatabase admin --db **MYDB** --collection **MYCOLLECTION** --type json --file **C:\PATH\IMPORT-FILE.json** --jsonArray